# When to create a branch from tag?

Tags: git, tags, git-branch

For a specific project, we are not planning for release

Using CI/CD approach, Dev pipeline is creating artifacts with name convention , something like: `1.0-23-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

We cannot create `release` branch from `develop` branch, to trigger QA pipeline, because there is no release, for this application, sooner.

**Goal** is to start QA phase.

QA pipeline need to be triggered on specific **tagged commit** on `develop` branch **but** create artifact something like: `${future_release_num}-${git_tag}-release.jar`

Source code build process generate the artifacts with such naming convention. Some dependent artifacts are placed by maven build in JFrog, so that they are pulled by `pom.xml` during maven build.

Developers are continuously working in `develop` branch.

---

Does branching from **tagged commit** resolve this problem? to trigger QA pipeline... We basically want to create this branch just for artifact naming convention

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a branch from a tag you can have

```
git checkout -b <branch_name_you_want_to_create> <tag>
```

However, I would recommend to place functionality generating an artefact name to the CI so you don't pollute your repository with many custom branch names. Instead, you can generate a name based on given SHA.

You can get the closes tag using:

```
git describe --abbrev=0
```

But still, the CI should know what you are going to release. It can be major version, minor or patch (provided you use semver at all).

Comment: But the source code build process is generating the artifact name, but not the jenkins pipeline